# Directory watcher for file open

Tags: c++, macos, winapi, filesystemwatcher

I am using `ReadDirectoryChanges` (for windows) and `FSEventStreamCreate` (for macosx) to watch for activities in a particular directory.

Unfortunately they both seem to be limited to reporting for events that modify in one or another way the content in the directory.

Is there any API (documented or not), tricks or whatever way that I can use to detect open for read access to a file in a directory.

P.S. My priority is windows and mac, but if you know how to do it in linux please feel free to share it.

Comment: I can't say with certainty, but I'd be very surprised if there were a way to do this short of writing a new driver or kernel extension (I believe that the Windows tool Process Monitor uses a driver to do its heavy lifting).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Process monitor (the file access part) is a good example of what I need. Do you know an open source project or any other place that I can see how this is done?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.

Comment: If you read the description for Process Monitor, it says: "Process Monitor works by extracting a file system filter device driver from its executable image (Procmon.exe) the first time you run it after a boot, installing the driver in memory, and then deleting the driver image from disk."  That driver is what intercepts file activity. You can read about [File System Filter Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382.aspx) on MSDN.